# Returned to my project and No textures show blender 2.92 but the textures nodes are still there

Tags: texturing, shaders, eevee-render-engine, output

So I have been working on this project for a few sessions and I go to open it back up after having added textures, lights and armature modifiers and everything still shows up when I reopen the project except for the textures. Texture nodes are there, the environment hdri node is still there, lights are there and fbx files still posed but no textures show in shader view and when i render the image all i see is transparency squares. Does anyone what is wrong with my project file and or how can i restore the texures to keep working?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably deleted your textures on you hard drive or moved them away. They don't follow your blend file unless you pack them. If you go to `File` > `External Data` > `Report Missing Files`, you can have a list of all the textures and external files that Blender can't find. If you know where your textures are located on your hard drive, you can do `File` > `External Data` > `Find Missing Files` and chose the directory where they are stored and Blender will add them back.

Comment: You are in _SOLID_ preview mode (default when restarting blender). Press Z in the 3D viewport and select either "Material Preview" or "Rendered" from the pie menu that appears, or pick one of the two rightmost of the 4 little circles in the top-right of the viewport (Left to right > Wireframe - Solid - Material - Rendered).

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka The screenshot shows only procedural textures, they are not external textures to be found by _Find Missing Files_. As Christopher says, it's _Solid View_ where you can't see the textures by default.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't take a closer look at the screenshots.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett THANK YOU! That was the solution to my issue exactly. I appreciate your help :)